# Is isset($foo) functionally identical to !$foo?

Tags: php

Will `isset($foo)` always display the same result as `!$foo`?

I have a peice of code where I'm getting php warnings for using:

```
if(!$foo){}
```

And I'm pretty sure that I should be using:

```
if(!isset($foo)){}
```

And that made me curious whether I'm changing the functionality here or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

Using a boolean negation operator `!` a variable is casted to boolean. Boolean `FALSE` is equal to `NULL` (this is functionally however the same as `isset()`), empty string, 0, empty array.

Using `isset` no error is given if the variable does not exist. If you use `!` with non-existent variable, `E_NOTICE` is shown.

Answer (score 8):

No.

One tests if a value is not set, the other tests if it is not true.

Compare:

```
<?php
$foo = 0;

if(!$foo){ echo 1; }
if(!isset($foo)){ echo 2; }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

it depends on what foo is.

Foo can be set to 1 or some value that you apply the not to. So even though the variable is set, you might get unintended behaviour